# Global font size of annotation boxes in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, annotations, global-variables, font-size

In matplotlib,
How can I update the annotation boxes font size globally?

I'm trying to do

```
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'axes.annotate.fontsize': 13})
```

but it is not working

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "annotation boxes"?  Legends, etc, or things placed with the `annotate` method? If you want to all fonts larger, you can update `font.size`.

Comment: Yes, I want the fonts with the `annotate` (http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) method to be smaller. I used `font.size` but it updates all the fonts. Until now I just specify `fontsize=` inside an `ax.annotate`

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to change just the default text size for `annotate`.  As you've noticed, `font.size` is meant to change _everything_.  If you really wanted, you could monkey-patch `annotate`, but explicitly specifying `size` (or `fontsize`, they're equivalent) in your calls to annotate is probably a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the source it does not seem that there would be such parameter. The `matplotlib.text.Annotation` objects are based on `matplotlib.text.Text` objects, there is no difference in the actual text rendering. So, they obey the `rcParams[´font.size']` (which is also used by axis labels).

Building the desired functionality would not be very difficult, but you would need to:

- add the parameter descriptions to `rcsetup.py`
- add the handling of the `annotate.*` parameters to `Annotate.__init__` in `text.py`